# Error when installing ClickOnce application on Windows versions below 10

Tags: .net, windows, winforms, clickonce, culture

Every time I've tested to install the application on a virtual Windows 7, 8 or 8.1, it always fails to install due to an error, but when one of my friends installed it on Windows 10, it worked perfectly fine. I do not understand what the issue is.

The main part of the error is this part here:

```
aa-DJ is an invalid culture identifier.
```

Which makes absolutely no sense to me, and this problem has never occurred before until now.

Here's the full error log:

```
PLATFORM VERSION INFO
    Windows             : 6.1.7601.65536 (Win32NT)
    Common Language Runtime     : 4.0.30319.42000
    System.Deployment.dll       : 4.6.1055.0 built by: NETFXREL2
    clr.dll             : 4.6.1076.0 built by: NETFXREL3STAGE
    dfdll.dll           : 4.6.1055.0 built by: NETFXREL2
    dfshim.dll          : 4.0.41209.0 (Main.041209-0000)

SOURCES
    Deployment url          : file:///C:/Users/Jazzy/AppData/Local/Temp/Anime%20Yu-Gi-Oh%20Card%20Maker.application
    Application url         : file:///C:/Users/Jazzy/AppData/Local/Temp/Application%20Files/Anime%20Yu-Gi-Oh%20Card%20Maker_5_1_0_0/Anime%20Yu-Gi-Oh%20Card%20Maker.exe.manifest

IDENTITIES
    Deployment Identity     : Anime Yu-Gi-Oh Card Maker.application, Version=5.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=a899559596d8a437, processorArchitecture=x86
    Application Identity        : Anime Yu-Gi-Oh Card Maker.exe, Version=5.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=a899559596d8a437, processorArchitecture=x86, type=win32

APPLICATION SUMMARY
    * Installable application.
    * Trust url parameter is set.
ERROR SUMMARY
    Below is a summary of the errors, details of these errors are listed later in the log.
    * Activation of C:\Users\Jazzy\AppData\Local\Temp\Anime Yu-Gi-Oh Card Maker.application resulted in exception. Following failure messages were detected:
        + Culture is not supported.
Parameter name: name
aa-DJ is an invalid culture identifier.

COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION FAILURE SUMMARY
    No transaction error was detected.

WARNINGS
    There were no warnings during this operation.

OPERATION PROGRESS STATUS
    * [20/06/2016 11:38:04 PM] : Activation of C:\Users\Jazzy\AppData\Local\Temp\Anime Yu-Gi-Oh Card Maker.application has started.
    * [20/06/2016 11:38:04 PM] : Processing of deployment manifest has successfully completed.
    * [20/06/2016 11:38:04 PM] : Installation of the application has started.
    * [20/06/2016 11:38:04 PM] : Processing of application manifest has successfully completed.
    * [20/06/2016 11:38:10 PM] : Found compatible runtime version 4.0.30319.
    * [20/06/2016 11:38:10 PM] : Request of trust and detection of platform is complete.

ERROR DETAILS
    Following errors were detected during this operation.
    * [20/06/2016 11:38:10 PM] System.Globalization.CultureNotFoundException
        - Culture is not supported.
Parameter name: name
aa-DJ is an invalid culture identifier.
        - Source: mscorlib
        - Stack trace:
            at System.Globalization.CultureInfo..ctor(String name, Boolean useUserOverride)
            at System.Deployment.Application.AssemblyMetaDataImport.ConstructAssemblyName(IntPtr asmMetaPtr, Char[] asmNameBuf, UInt32 asmNameLength, IntPtr pubKeyPtr, UInt32 pubKeyBytes, UInt32 flags)
            at System.Deployment.Application.AssemblyMetaDataImport.ImportIdentity()
            at System.Deployment.Application.AssemblyMetaDataImport.get_Name()
            at System.Deployment.Application.Manifest.AssemblyManifest.LoadFromCompLibAssembly(String filePath)
            at System.Deployment.Application.Manifest.AssemblyManifest.LoadFromInternalManifestFile(String filePath)
            at System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.ProcessDownloadedFile(Object sender, DownloadEventArgs e)
            at System.Deployment.Application.FileDownloader.DownloadModifiedEventHandler.Invoke(Object sender, DownloadEventArgs e)
            at System.Deployment.Application.FileDownloader.OnModified()
            at System.Deployment.Application.SystemNetDownloader.DownloadSingleFile(DownloadQueueItem next)
            at System.Deployment.Application.SystemNetDownloader.DownloadAllFiles()
            at System.Deployment.Application.FileDownloader.Download(SubscriptionState subState)
            at System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.DownloadDependencies(SubscriptionState subState, AssemblyManifest deployManifest, AssemblyManifest appManifest, Uri sourceUriBase, String targetDirectory, String group, IDownloadNotification notification, DownloadOptions options)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.DownloadApplication(SubscriptionState subState, ActivationDescription actDesc, Int64 transactionId, TempDirectory& downloadTemp)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.InstallApplication(SubscriptionState& subState, ActivationDescription actDesc)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentActivation(Uri activationUri, Boolean isShortcut, String textualSubId, String deploymentProviderUrlFromExtension, BrowserSettings browserSettings, String& errorPageUrl)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.ActivateDeploymentWorker(Object state)

COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION DETAILS
    No transaction information is available.
```

Comment: `aa-DJ` is for `Afar` language  and `Djibouti` location. It is not supported on OS version lower than `Windows 10` and `Windows Server 2016 Technical Preview.`. Take a look at [Windows Language Code Identifier (LCID) Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc233965.aspx).

Comment: Do you have any idea how to fix this? Maybe add the language support manually, or remove it from Windows 10? I'd like users to be able to use this on different OS versions and not be bound to windows 10.

Comment: Do you have a form localized in `aa-DJ` culture? Look at `bin\debug` folder and check if a `aa-DJ` folder exists there. If yes, you can remove resource files which are for `aa-DJ` and build your application again.

Comment: Right, the folder exists, so you are saying if I just remove this folder, the problem is fixed?

Comment: It's better to go to your project and look at resource files under forms and remove them if they are `Something.aa-DJ.Resx`

Comment: @RezaAghaei Okay I found the culprit Resx file and deleted it. If this fixes it entirely, you should post this as an answer for future reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`aa-DJ` is the language identifier for `Afar` language and `Djibouti` location. It is not supported on OS version lower than `Windows 10` and `Windows Server 2016 Technical Preview`.

You have some localized form in `aa-DJ` culture in your project. To solve the problem, you can check if there is a `.aa-DJ.Resx` file under any of forms, remove it.

For more information about supported language code identifiers take a look at [Windows Language Code Identifier (LCID) Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc233965.aspx)

Comment: Thank you! So far, this seems to have fixed it. Let's hope it remains that way.